# C++ non-blocking proxy check/open

Tags: php, c++, node.js

I have an issue with a program written in `C++`. I want to open a SOCKS5 proxy on a free port then check if is ok (check with curl), then release the I/O blocking.
This is the code :

**C++**

```
main()
{
    char* s_sockshost = "127.0.0.1";
    socks_port = find_empty_port();

    if(fork())
    {
        // child process continues and opens a socks
        open_proxy();
    }
    else
    {
        // parrent process just checks something then dies      
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            proxytest = curlsockstest(s_sockshost,socks_port);

            if(proxytest)
            {
                break;
            }

            sleep(1);
        }

        if(proxytest)
        {
            if(hitdebug >= 3) printf("check_result : is opened on %s",socks_port);

            exit(0); // kill just this process
        }
        else
        {
            if(hitdebug >= 3) printf("check_result : is bad\n");

            kill(getppid(), SIGKILL); // kill both processes
        }
    }
}
```

If i do this from cmd like

```
./proxy; ls -al;
```

then it is executing and executes the command after it, but if i do it from PHP or NODEJS it is hanging, like expecting to finish.

**NODEJS:**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = './proxy; ls -al;';


setTimeout(function(){

    console.log("Timer");

    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("error: ");
        console.log(error);
        console.log();

        console.log("stdout: ");
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log();

        console.log("stderr: ");
        console.log(stderr);
        console.log();
    });

    console.log("Timer end");

},2000);
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

echo "Run start\n";
$array_exec = array();
// exec("./proxy",$array_exec);
system("./proxy");

var_dump($array_exec);
echo "Run end\n";

?>
```

What is the explination and how can i solve this?

I am thinking to make PHP and NODEJS comunicating with this C++ app with `sqlite` or something like that...

Comment: I think you got the cases mixed. if `fork` succeeds then parent get some value > 0 and the child process gets 0.

Comment: curlsockstest and open_proxy doesn't seem to be by google part of some library API. can you share their impl? I am not expert in node.js or php, but if both outside application and hanging, maybe something is wrong in the C program. probably the way the process are killed and free their resources.

Comment: it is like the process1 (parent) stays, child dies, then the PHP waits till the last of data is sent, i want something to deatach() or something, do you know someway to read real time from command stream and if a var encounters to deatch() from the process?

Comment: Currently your father is the one opening the proxy and not your child process. I am not sure why as a standalone `./proxy` "exits". Therefore it won't die and wont be used as a side process as in @Mason. Mason change of execution method is good, but i think you just patch up a bug in the c++ program in the overlaying php/node.js code.

You second question is little blurred. I think that a primitive Linux message queue will do the job, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The `system()` function would wait until the process is finished and collect the entire output.

You should either use daemon for your C++ or you can simply change it to: `./proxy &` and if you don't need output, `./proxy & > /dev/null`

```
<?php
echo "Run start\n";
$array_exec = array();

shell_exec("./proxy &",$array_exec);
var_dump($array_exec);
echo "Run end\n";
?>
```

Comment: that's the tricky part, i need the output of the `fork()`, to say if the proxy is good or bad, but it is looks like as long as `fork()` or `parent` is alive, `PHP `will wait ...

Answer (score 2):

**Node.js**

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('proxy');//@see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}. We should stop the child_process`);
  ls.kill('SIGTSTP');
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

**Update**

> instead of kill can it be something as deatach() instead of `ls.kill('SIGTERM');` ? like send it in background? i will try also your variant, it will help me also

This is not part of Node.js staff. There is a part of the Unix signals list:

- `SIGINT` means interrupt. By default, this signal causes the process to terminate. In terminal you can press Ctrl-C (in older Unixes, DEL) for sending SIGINT;
- `SIGTSTP` means terminal stop. By default, this signal causes the process to suspend execution. In terminal you can press Ctrl-Z for sending SIGTSTP;
- `SIGQUIT` means quit. This signal causes the process to terminate and dump core. In terminal you can press Ctrl-| for sending SIGTSTP.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is looking good, event style programing, but can i do something in `data` event, if i encounter something to `deatach()` from the process? or something?

Comment: I added stopping for the process on any data in error stream. Does it what you need?

Comment: instead of kill can it be something as `deatach()` instead of ` ls.kill('SIGTERM');` ? like send it in background? i will try also your variant, it will help me also

Comment: I added updated about nginx signals. I changed `SIGINT => SIGTSTP`. It's work for me. Could you check?

Comment: those will kill the process with different signals, and `SIGTSTP` mean halt the process, is there a way to attach that pid to a different `tty` ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your requirements. Could you provide bash script with required behaviour? I will help you implement it with Node.js